# Can't add modules on project structure in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-library, android-holo-everywhere, project-structure

The structure project window does not show all the options and I can not add libraries or modules.

Check the image:
[image]

And this is how it should look with all the options:
[image]

I try to fix that reinstalling androidstudio, but it didn't work.
I'm using Android Studio 2.9 and i already have working ABS, but i can't make work HoloEverywhere

Is there any solution for this problem?
Beforehand, thanks

Comment: Have the same problem. Did you find valid solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do Right Mouse Click on visible package, then select 'Open Module Settings' - it will give you ability to add Module.

I added a screenshot to show exacly what I mean.

[image]

It's a workaround but it give you ability to add module to project

Comment: I'm having this exact problem. However, I want to import a module (socialauth-android) so I can use it in my project. I don't see any way to do that from the right-click

Comment: It doesn't give the workaround. it just show the popup but the gradle doesn't change as I setting the project.